# VB.NET .NET after load event?

Tags: vb.net, events

I need some way of knowing when a form has finished loading. My reasoning is I have a second form that is loaded when this form loads. The code for this is called from `form1.load`.

`Form2` is currently being displayed behind `form1` as I am guessing `form1` calls an activate or similar at the end of the load so any Activate, BringToFront, etc. calls on `form2` are overridden.

If you look at the code below, I have tried adding `frmAllocationSearch.Activate`, `frmAllocationSearch.BringToFront` and `Me.SendToBack` after the call to `ShowAlloactionSearchDialog()`,  but these are all wasted as something is happening after the load event is fired to bring `Me` to the front.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Allocation_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                            Handles Me.Load

    ShowAlloactionSearchDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAlloactionSearchDialog()

    If frmAllocationSearch Is Nothing OrElse frmAllocationSearch.IsDisposed Then
        frmAllocationSearch = New AllocationSearch
        frmAllocationSearch.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        frmAllocationSearch.Info = Me.Info
        frmAllocationSearch.Top = Me.Top
        frmAllocationSearch.Left = Me.Left + Me.Width - frmAllocationSearch.Width
        frmAllocationSearch.AllocationWindow = Me

        frmAllocationSearch.Show()
    Else
        If frmAllocationSearch.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            frmAllocationSearch.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        End IF
        frmAllocationSearch.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try the [Form.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event.

> Occurs when the form is activated in code or by the user.

Comment: I had to add a flag to prevent it being on top all the time but this was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the Forms 'Shown' Event

Comment: This event is still in the initialization process. The Form is not fully loaded when this event is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer control for delayed start of a function. Enable the timer at design time and disable it at the time of first execution of the `timer.tick` event. Set the `interval` to 500 for a comfortable delayed start.

Or you can use the `Form.Shown` event directly, but it will start immediately without giving any delay.